# Change basic php to if statement php

Tags: php, syntax

I need help breaking apart the php code that's inside the  tag.
Basically I only want the button to appear if there is a link. If there is no link, I don't want the empty button to appear. Any ideas how to do this?

```
<div class="button"><a href="<?php the_sub_field( 'funding_link' ); ?>">Donate</a></div>
```

Comment: Add a condition? What issue are you facing?

Comment: Basically, the full issue I'm facing is that I'm trying to create a custom post type template for the first time, and I want certain post-type content to appear if there is any content in it.

Answer (score 2):

`the_sub_field()` function may produce output (the link), or not.

The first thing to do is capture that output using an [**output buffer**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) in order to check it's contents:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    the_sub_field( 'funding_link' );
    $link = ob_get_clean();
```

Next just check the content of `$link`: if not an empty string then output the button's HTML code

```
    if( $link != "" )
    {
        echo "<div class=\"button\"><a href=\"$link\">Donate</a></div>";
    }
```

Finally close the PHP code block

```
?>
```

---

If you're using [**advanced custom fields**](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_sub_field/) then

`the_sub_field(...)`

is equivalent to

`echo get_sub_field(...)`

In this case the solution is simplier as you can just get the link into a variable without using a buffer:

```
<?php
    $link = get_sub_field( 'funding_link' );
    if( $link != "" )
    {
        echo "<div class=\"button\"><a href=\"$link\">Donate</a></div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I appreciate everyone's help.
I figured this out with the following addition

```
<?php if( get_sub_field('funding_link') ): ?>
<div class="button"><a href="<?php the_sub_field( 'funding_link' ); ?>">Donate</a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as i can see you have html on your php file, one way to do it is like this

```
<?php
    $mycondition = false;
    // your condition should be something like
    // $mycondition = the_sub_field( 'funding_link' );
    // if the string is empty it's also considered a false value
?>
<?php if($mycondition):?>
    <a href="somelink.html">Donate</a>
<?php else:?>
    <!--here goes nothing-->
<?php endif;?>
```

**Another way to do it**
with a shothand if

```
<?=($condition)?"let's show the link":"let's show nothing"?>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9DsIgEIDn8hRn46ADulsKiy9C9OgRyx0pLD49Eo3G@fvJlFszLlNWwz49b8L3WKMwzBD8WnBSzqo3hxgO/8bx0slgPNCGYR6LJFwjP05U0zraq7CvaM7@W2OffYqd1oQbwiJYgKVS5EXrn9f3YXK2tRc)